# Accessing an element class to where you're at in the DOM (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, dom, loops, web

I have the following DOM structure:

```
<div id="cont">
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="c1"><span class="c2">...</span><span class="c3">...</span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="c1"><span class="c2">...</span><span class="c3">...</span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="c1"><span class="c2">...</span><span class="c3">...</span></span>
    </li>
    ...
    <li>
        <span class="c1"><span class="c2">...</span><span class="c3">...</span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

with the following jQuery:

```
$("#cont ul li").each(function (e) {
    $(this).bind("mousemove",function(d) {
        var ele = $(this + " .c2");
        var ele2 = $(this " .c3");
        //do stuff
    });
});
```

What I would like to do is access "c2" and "c3" elements relative to the current dom position.  I would like the loop to select the following relative to the top of the DOM:

```
ele = $("#cont ul li span .c2");
ele = $("#cont ul li span .c3");
//Do Stuff
//Move to the next set of Li's
ele = $("#cont ul li span .c2");
ele = $("#cont ul li span .c3");
//Do Stuff
//Move to the next set of Li's
ele = $("#cont ul li span .c2");
ele = $("#cont ul li span .c3");
//Do Stuff
//Move to the next set of Li's
..
```

Comment: Mind if I ask what "`//Do Stuff`" does? You may not even need the `.each()` loop...

Comment: Do stuff does calculations with image sizes in the spans.  Each image is a different size.  It matters.  I used the examples here and my code works.  Upvotes all around!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to select descendants of the current matched element.

```
$("#cont ul li").each(function (e) {
    $(this).bind("mousemove",function(d) {
        var ele = $(this).find(".c2");
        var ele2 = $(this).find(".c3");
        //do stuff
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$("#cont ul li").each(function (e) {
  $(this).bind("mousemove",function(d) {
    var ele = $(this).find(".c2");
    var ele2 = $(this).find(".c3");
    //do stuff
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If li will always be an immediate parent, you can use:

```
var elem, elem2;
$('.c1').bind("mousemove",function(d) {
  elem=$(this).parent().find('.c2');
  elem2=$(this).parent().find('.c2');
  //Do stuff
})
```